# MediaWiki-API Installation on windows

Tags: windows, perl, installation, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

trying to automate using perl scripts on windows server using MediaWiki::Bot and Mediawiki::API taken from

[http://metacpan.org/pod/MediaWiki::Bot](http://metacpan.org/pod/MediaWiki%3a%3aBot)

[http://metacpan.org/pod/MediaWiki::API](http://metacpan.org/pod/MediaWiki%3a%3aAPI)

Installation issue

```
C:\Users\user\Downloads\MediaWiki-API-0.36>perl Makefile.PL
Set up gcc environment - 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3)
Writing Makefile for MediaWiki::API

C:\Users\user\Downloads\MediaWiki-API-0.36>make
/bin/sh: C:Perlbinperl.exe: command not found
make: *** [blib\lib\MediaWiki\\.exists] Error 127
```

same issue seen on MediaWiki-Bot too, so i just copied the API.pm and Bot.pm file to the c:/Perl/lib/MediaWiki folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's trying to find C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe but the path separators are being treated as escape characters. You can try replacing \ with / in your Makefile.

Answer (score -1):

Do following in bold font:

C:\Users\User\Desktop\MediaWiki-Bot-5.005004>**perl Makefile.PL**

> Set up gcc environment - gcc.exe (rubenvb-4.5.4) 4.5.4 Writing
>   Makefile for MediaWiki::Bot Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json

C:\Users\User\Desktop\MediaWiki-Bot-5.005004>**perl Build.PL**

> Set up gcc environment - gcc.exe (rubenvb-4.5.4) 4.5.4 Set up gcc
>   environment - gcc.exe (rubenvb-4.5.4) 4.5.4 Created MYMETA.yml and
>   MYMETA.json Creating new 'Build' script for 'MediaWiki-Bot' version
>   '5.005004'

C:\Users\User\Desktop\MediaWiki-Bot-5.005004>**Build.bat**

> Set up gcc environment - gcc.exe (rubenvb-4.5.4) 4.5.4 Set up gcc
>   environment - gcc.exe (rubenvb-4.5.4) 4.5.4 Set up gcc environment -
>   gcc.exe (rubenvb-4.5.4) 4.5.4 Building MediaWiki-Bot

Go to lib/MediaWiki Folder, copy the generated Bot.pm to the folder where your perl installed. Re-open your IDE or the source code in your IDE, it should work.

Comment: Not only is this post almost a year old, I find it very hard to believe that you are supposed to run both Makefile.PL and Build.PL, and finally the installer should be used to install, not manually copying. Much better to use [App::cpanminus](https://metacpan.org/module/App::cpanminus) to install and be done with it.

Comment: It works at my part. Just let you know. Taking point out from a worked solution is really discouraging

Comment: I'm sorry to have discouraged you, but your answer is fundamentally flawed. You should use `make` or `Build`, not both. You should do either `make install` or `Build install` rather than manually copying.  In fact if you do copy, you should copy from `/blib` not `/lib` as the latter is the pre-build directory. What you did MIGHT work in pure perl modules, it certainly won't always work. All that said, why not just use an installation client like `cpan` or `cpanm` in the first place?